# A 'for' loop that appears to be practically infinite

Tags: c++

I'm debugging some code at the moment, and I've come across this line:

```
for (std::size_t j = M; j <= M; --j)
```

(Written by my boss, who's on holiday.)

It looks really odd to me.

What does it do? To me, it looks like an infinite loop.

Comment: `size_t` is unsigned, so is guaranteed to wrap around to its maximum value when attempting to deprecate zero, ending the loop. Still horrible code though.

Comment: @BoBTFish: I actually quite like it; yes it does take a little time to get used to it.

Comment: @Bathsheba What if `M` happens to be the max value for `size_t`? Do you still think it is clever?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar It doesn't work for that case. Luckily, such loops are unlikely. That number doesn't come up much in the real world.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: I personally like it for its clarity, although I will confess that I use the `-->` "operator" for such cases in my code: I would always stumble over `j <= M` when reading this code, particularly at 3am with vi as the only editor available.

Comment: @Barmar *Doesn't come up much* is not *Never comes up*, so there is a probability > 0. Which means that this solution is stupid when there are ways to put it simple.

Comment: Neither can I unfortunately. But my mind turned to jelly when I saw the code above. I can't debug code I don't understand!

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting. This question is clear - I can't see how it could be improved. From a new user, this question is actually *interesting*!

Comment: `#define TRUE FALSE` and go on holiday.

Comment: @Bathsheba *why* do you like this code? It seems like an unreadable mess to me.

Comment: @sgroves possibly since I've been familiar with it since I was a young teenager. Counting unsigned types down to zero always introduces special considerations.

Comment: @Bathsheba ... which is exactly why it's terrible code. "clever" code is BAD CODE.

Comment: @BoBTFish: When attempting to .. "deprecate zero"?!

Comment: Terrible variable names and no commenting makes for hard-to-debug code for all. Dire.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`std::size_t` is guaranteed by the C++ standard to be a `unsigned` type. And if you decrement an `unsigned` type from 0, the standard guarantees that the result of doing that is the largest value for that type.

That wrapped-around value is always greater than or equal to `M`<sup>1</sup> so the loop terminates.

So `j <= M` when applied to an `unsigned` type is a convenient way of saying "run the loop to zero then stop".

Alternatives such as running `j` one greater than you want, and even using the *slide operator* `for (std::size_t j = M + 1; j --> 0; ){` exist, which are arguably clearer although require more typing. I guess one disadvantage though (other than the bewildering effect it produces on first inspection) is that it doesn't port well to languages with no unsigned types, such as Java.

Note also that the scheme that your boss has picked "borrows" a possible value from the `unsigned` set: it so happens in this case that `M` set to `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()` will not have the correct behaviour. **In fact, in that case, the loop is infinite**. (Is that what you're observing?) You ought to insert a comment to that effect in the code, and possibly even assert on that particular condition.

---

<sup>1</sup> Subject to `M` not being `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`.

Comment: @GillBates: Thank you. Eventually I'll get this answer right. Perhaps I should hang up my tools for the day.

Comment: I'm blaming the weather.

Comment: If M is `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()` then `M + 1` will be zero, and the `for (std::size_t j = M + 1; j --> 0; )` loop will not loop at all.

Comment: Don't call it the "slide operator". There is no such operator in C++, it's just a clever-looking obfuscation.

Comment: @You

Why? Its such a nice interview question:     

How will you define the slide operator in C++ in this case: for( size_t i{200}; i --> 0;    ) {...}

Comment: @DimitarMirchev: Because it's not an operator. It's two operators, with odd spacing. Call it an idiom if you insist on asking interviewees irrelevant questions (but ideally, ask them how they would implement the functionality instead of asking about the "clever" syntax).

Comment: Assuming that `size_t` is 64 bits,it will take several hundred years to observe the incorrect behaviour in the edge case. (Except if the optimiser can get rid of the loop.)

Comment: Note that the alternative `for (std::size_t j = M+1; j-->0; )` has the great advantage of making it more obvious that the loop runs `M+1` times, not `M` times. In fact in C++ one almost almost wants to specify a range using one more than the highest value inside the range, and the OP code looks like a likely off-by-one error (for instance if `M` is the size of some array). In fact personally find the alternative is in all ways superior to the OP code.

Comment: Well, assuming `M` isn't `max_size_t` :-)

Comment: Why would anybody actually write this though? Why not just let j start from zero and stop when it's bigger than M? The only thing I can think of which might be useful is to use the value of j directly inside of the loop instead of having to substitute it from M, etc. But still this kind of looping condition seems way too unintuitive.

Answer (score 27):

What your boss was probably *trying* to do was to count down from `M` to zero inclusive, performing some action on each number.

Unfortunately there's an edge case where that will *indeed* give you an infinite loop, the one where `M` is the maximum `size_t` value you can have. And, although it's well defined what an unsigned value will do when you decrement it from zero, I maintain that the code itself is an example of sloppy thinking, especially as there's a perfectly viable solution without the shortcomings of your bosses attempt.

That safer variant (and more readable, in my opinion, while still maintaining a tight scope limit), would be:

```
{
    std::size_t j = M;
    do {
        doSomethingWith(j);
    } while (j-- != 0);
}
```

By way of example, see the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <climits>
int main (void) {
    uint32_t quant = 0;
    unsigned short us = USHRT_MAX;
    std::cout << "Starting at " << us;
    do {
        quant++;
    } while (us-- != 0);
    std::cout << ", we would loop " << quant << " times.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This does basically the same thing with an `unsigned short` and you can see it processes *every* single value:

```
Starting at 65535, we would loop 65536 times.
```

Replacing the `do..while` loop in the above code with what your boss basically did will result in an infinite loop. Try it and see:

```
for (unsigned int us2 = us; us2 <= us; --us2) {
    quant++;
}
```

Comment: Now, the edge case is `0`. Why not `for(size_t j = M; j-- != 0; )`?

Comment: Yes, this does suffer from the corner case being perhaps more frequent than `numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`.

Comment: @Logic et al, there is no edge case in the method I provided, I've added code to show this. With your *proposed* solution, an initial value of `M == 0` will result in the element 0 not being processed, so it *does* have an edge case. Using my post-check `do..while` method eliminates the edge case altogether. If you try it with `M == 1`, you'll see it does both 1 *and* 0. Similarly, start it with `max_size_t` (whatever that happens to be) and it will successfully start at that point then decrement down to and including zero.

Comment: Interestingly this case motivates use of what some would say is “not structured code” because it uses an “`exitif`”, namely `{ j =M; for(;;){ f(j); if( j == 0 )break; j -= 1; } }`. One might even need to replace the `break` with a `goto` if things get nested, since C has no named loops. If “structured” means “susceptible to reasoning about chunks” it is structured (layout helps!), and also if it means “susceptible to formal validation by reasoning about pre- and post-conditions”. Though in this case `j--` works, exitif style may be justified when a more complicated transition is required.

Comment: @PJTraill I can't tell what you are saying is structured and what you are saying is not structured. Reasoning about do-while is straightforward. It doesn't "use" an exit any more than, or in any more of an unstructured way, while-do does.

Comment: @philipxy: Sorry if I was cryptic. I had in mind the reaction of a colleague to a language (DECTPU) containing an `exitif` keyword: he said disapprovingly (in Dutch) “But that’s not structured!”, which got me thinking about what people meant by “structured” and why Dijkstra _et al._ introduced the concept. In this case I was suggesting that some – such as my colleague – might call the fragment of C in my comment “not structured”, though there are arguments in its favour. I was not contrasting `do…while` with `while…do`.